# Secondary y-axis is not plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pivot-table, bar-chart

I created a bar plot and now I want to add a secondary y-axis as a line using 'Recovered' from my pivot table. Unfortunately, the data for secondary y-axis is not showing but the axis is displaying correctly.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

```
pivot['Unrecovered'] = pivot['Claim'] - pivot['Paid']
pivot['Recovered'] = (pivot['Paid'] / pivot['Claim'])*100
pivot
```

pivot output:

| Fiscal Year | Claim | Paid | Unrecovered | Recovered |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 788,602.37 | 610,283.05 | 178,319.32 | 77.39 |
| 2019 | 9,870,246.71 | 7,834,106.99 | 2,036,139.72 | 79.37 |
| 2020 | 7,661,541.11 | 5,839,581.89 | 1,821,959.22 | 76.22 |
| 2021 | 6,641,099.86 | 4,641,853.93 | 1,999,245.93 | 69.90 |
| 2022 | 3,124,225.48 | 700,148.52 | 2,424,076.96 | 22.41 |

```
# plot pivot table with secondary y-axis showing % Recovered

pivot.plot(y = ['Paid','Unrecovered'],
       kind='bar',
       rot=0,
       stacked = True,
       ylabel ='Amount ($)')
plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')
ax = pivot["Recovered"].plot(secondary_y = True, 
                         color = 'k',
                         marker = 'o')
ax.set_ylabel("Recovered")
ax.set_ylim(0,100)
plt.show()
```

Output : [Recovered plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei8GQ.png)

Comment: The secondary line plot shows up fine on my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UHbl.png

Comment: What's your `pd.__version__` and `matplotlib.__version__`? I created the above with pd 1.4.1 and mpl 3.5.1

Comment: pd.__version__  = 1.2.3  and matplotlib.__version__=3.3.1   I'm updating my libraries since they are way out of date

Comment: Actually I just realized it's probably because your `Fiscal Year` is the index. You should reset the index for the line plot (but not the bar plot): `pivot.reset_index()["Recovered"].plot(secondary_y=True, ...)`

Comment: The panda update from conda seems to have broken my environment now :(

Comment: @tdy That worked! One last question.... do you know how to format the x-axis range so there's commas separating the large numbers? Alternatively, I would be also happy with eliminating all the extra zeros in the x-axis. Any recommendations?

Comment: You mean the y-axis? Save the bar plot's axes like you did with the line plot (say as `ax1`) and apply a comma f-string using a ticker formatter: `ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: f'{y:,.0f}'))`

Comment: @tdy I'm getting an error --- NameError: name matplotlib is not defined. I've copied my code as it now appears. I think I did something wrong with labeling ax1     

'ax1=pivot.plot(y = ['Paid','Unrecovered'],kind='bar',rot=0,stacked = True,ylabel ='Amount ($)')'

'ax1.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: f'{y:,.0f}'))'

plt.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y')

ax = pivot.reset_index()["Recovered"].plot(secondary_y = True, color = 'k',marker = 'o')

ax.set_ylabel("Recovered ($)")

ax.set_ylim(0,100)

plt.show()'

Comment: I am also having trouble showing my code in comments the same way that you do. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Sorry for the way it's showing up

Comment: oh I figured out what the problem is. I had 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt' but I also needed to add 'import matplotlib' by itself. Though now I'm getting 2 attribute errors. The first is that 'FuncFormatter' object has no attribute 'set_scientific'. The second is that 'This method only works with the Scalar Formatter.

Comment: @tdy Nevermind! I got it to work! Thank you!